# Does 3D content require special HDMI cables?

Tags: hdmi, hdtv, 3d

I recently started reading up on [HDMI versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi#Versions). Do the different versions of HDMI need different cables?

In particular, I am concerned if I should get new cables in order to support 3D ([some](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019EHU8G) cables advertise their 3D support, but I'm not sure if that's just a marketing gimmick). I will be picking up my new 3D display tomorrow and I want to make sure I have everything I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3D technology is evolving rapidly, with several competing approaches under development, so the HDMI 1.4 specification establishes protocols for a number of popular 3D display methods, including:

- Frame, line, or field alternative methods
- Side by side methods (full and half)
- 2D plus depth methods
  A complete list of the supported 3D formats can be found in the HDMI 1.4 specification.

How to Ensure 3D in your Home Theater System:

- Look for devices that include 3D functionality.

### All High Speed HDMI cables will support 3D when connected to 3D devices. You can use your existing High Speed HDMI cables or choose a different cable type.

[More info available here](http://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmi_1_4/finding_right_cable.aspx)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Is there a difference between `high speed` HDMI cables and HDMI cables that I threw out the packaging for eons ago and can't remember if the packaging said `high speed`? Basically: is there a real difference between the various types of HDMI cables?

Comment: Fixed broken link.  see the link for the real differences between them.  Its from HDMI.org.  **if you want a 3D home theater experience, the difference is black and white... Get a High Speed HDMI cable.  High Speed = 3D.

Comment: High Speed HDMI Cable
The High Speed HDMI cable is designed and tested to handle video resolutions of 1080p and beyond, including advanced display technologies such as 4K, 3D, and Deep Color. If you are using any of these technologies, or if you are connecting your 1080p display to a 1080p content source, such as a Blu-ray Disc player, this is the recommended cable.

Comment: do you want to know how to tell what kind of HDMI cable you have?

Answer (score 0):

3D support is not a marketing gimmick (golden connectors are). 3D content requires a much higher bandwidth since much more data is transferred in comparison to 2D HDMI. HDMI High Speed cables provide 10.2 Gbps which is enough for 3D HD video material. However, in order to be 100% sure that your cable supports 3D make sure that the 3D functionality is listed on the product description (besides the High Speed logo). If you are looking to buy HDMI cables, note that there are other criteria except the cable version / features that need to be considered (see [Difference in HDMI Cables](http://hdmiguru.hubpages.com/hub/Difference-in-HDMI-Cables-5-Differentiating-Factors-to-Remember))